# keepalived exiting with code 256 on FAULT state in systemd when built from source

Tags: centos7, systemd

I’m having a little trouble getting keepalived to work using systemd when building from source. I copied the unit file from a package-installed keepalived available to centos 7, and it mostly works in that it does start and stop the keepalived process, but when keepalived goes into its FAULT state, systemd shows that it continually exits with the code 256. when installed from the package it shows the FAULT state properly. I’m not sure what the difference is between the two installations concerning systemd.

```
[Unit]
Description=LVS and VRRP High Availability Monitor
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
KillMode=process
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/keepalived
ExecStart=/usr/local/sbin/keepalived $KEEPALIVED_OPTIONS
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
PIDFile=/var/run/keepalived.pid

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The process starts and stops fine, but when a FAULT state is encountered, I get this:

```
● keepalived.service - LVS and VRRP High Availability Monitor
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/keepalived.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2016-10-01 00:47:12 EDT; 2s ago
  Process: 30947 ExecStart=/usr/local/sbin/keepalived $KEEPALIVED_OPTIONS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 30948 (keepalived)
   CGroup: /system.slice/keepalived.service
           ├─30948 /usr/local/sbin/keepalived -D
           ├─30949 /usr/local/sbin/keepalived -D
           └─30950 /usr/local/sbin/keepalived -D

Oct 01 00:47:12 server.test.com Keepalived_vrrp[30950]: Registering gratuitous ARP shared channel
Oct 01 00:47:12 server.test.com Keepalived_vrrp[30950]: Opening file '/etc/keepalived/keepalived.conf'.
Oct 01 00:47:12 server.test.com Keepalived_vrrp[30950]: Truncating auth_pass to 8 characters
Oct 01 00:47:12 server.test.com Keepalived_vrrp[30950]: VRRP_Instance(VPN) removing protocol VIPs.
Oct 01 00:47:12 server.test.com Keepalived_vrrp[30950]: Using LinkWatch kernel netlink reflector...
Oct 01 00:47:12 server.test.com Keepalived_vrrp[30950]: VRRP_Instance(VPN) Entering BACKUP STATE
Oct 01 00:47:12 server.test.com Keepalived_vrrp[30950]: VRRP sockpool: [ifindex(3), proto(112), unicast(1), fd(10,11)]
Oct 01 00:47:12 server.test.com Keepalived_vrrp[30950]: pid 30951 exited with status 256
Oct 01 00:47:13 server.test.com Keepalived_vrrp[30950]: pid 30953 exited with status 256
```

Answer (score 0):

After much help from the maintainer of the [keepalived project](https://github.com/acassen/keepalived/issues/438), it was determined that keepalived was actually entering a FAULT state, but then verbosely logging that the `vrrp_script` was failing, which is something added after the version available to the centos yum repo.